# rails ajax post works inconsistently

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

OK, this one is driving me crazy.  First of all, everything works fine in my development environment.  In production, however, the behavior is inconsistent across multiple browsers.  Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.  I'm using Rails 3.1 and jQuery 1.8.2.  I had been using jQuery 1.4.1 and it wasn't working then, either.

Here's what should happen: the user clicks a "Save" button and the client sends JSON-formatted data to rails which uses it to create several new "response" items and then redirects the user to the controller "show" action (the user answers the poll and then sees the results for all users).

Here is the relevant code from my view (answer.html):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    'beforeSend': function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")
    }
});

$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
  var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
});

var plot;
var dataseries = [[[null,null]],[[null,null]],[[null,null]],[[null,null]],[[null,null]],[[null,null]],[[null,null]],[[null,null]],[[null,null]]];

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.save_button').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var numItems = dataseries.length;
    var item;
    var sequence;
    var question = <%=@question.id%>;

    var dataArray = new Array();

    for (i=0;i<numItems;i++){
        var requestObj = {
          question_id: "<%=@question.id%>",
          user_id: "<%= @user %>",      
    }
        item = $('.item_list li[data-seq='+i+']').attr('id');
        requestObj["item_id"] = item;
        requestObj["x"]= dataseries[i][0][0];
        requestObj["y"]= dataseries[i][0][1];

    if (requestObj["item_id"]>0 && requestObj["x"]!=null && requestObj["y"]!=null ){
        dataArray.push(requestObj);
    }


    }
    var dataString = JSON.stringify(dataArray);
    var a = $.ajax({
    url: "/responses/batchCreate",
    data: dataString,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert('error:');
    },
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': '<%= form_authenticity_token.to_s %>'
    }
    })


    window.location.replace("<%=question_path(@question)%>");
});
```

The $('.save_button').click(function(event) fires every time.  The "error" callback fires every time, too - but sometimes it works!

Here is the relevant controller code:

```
def batchCreate
        logger.info "RECEIVED AJAX DATA!!!!"
        responses = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.body.read)
        responses.each do |resp|
          if (resp["item_id"]!=:null && resp["x"]!=:null && resp["y"]!=:null )
            @response = Response.new()
            if resp["user_id"]!=""
              @response.user_id=resp["user_id"];
            else
              u = User.where(:token => cookies[:user]).first
              if u.nil?
                u = User.create!(:email => "guest_#{Time.now.to_i}#{rand(99)}@example.com", :password => cookies[:user], :token => cookies[:user])
                @response.user_id=u.id
              else
                @response.user_id = u.id
              end
            end

            @response.question_id=resp["question_id"].to_i
            @response.item_id = resp["item_id"].to_i
            @response.x = resp["x"].to_i
            @response.y = resp["y"].to_i
            @response.save
          end
        end

    respond_to do |format|

        format.html { redirect_to @response, :notice => 'Question was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :json => response, :status => :created, :location => @response }
        format.js 

    end

  end
```

Sometimes the data are saved, new responses are created in my DB, and the page redirects to the show action.  Other times, it just reloads the page.  In these instances, it doesn't appear that the post data are reaching the server - I see nothing in production.log.

I'm a complete beginner to ajax and only slightly more competent at Rails.  Any insight you can provide on even how to begin to troubleshoot this issue would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line at the end of your click handler will reload the page on every click:

```
 window.location.replace("<%=question_path(@question)%>");
```

Because of this redirect the AJAX request may or may not complete depending on the timing of execution.  I think this is the cause of your inconsistent results.  Perhaps the execution times in your development environment are such that you do not encounter problems locally.

I think you may want to move that line of code inside of the success response handler so that a redirect occurs only if the AJAX request was successful

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  window.location.replace("<%=question_path(@question)%>");
}
```

I would avoid using embedded Ruby code to generate JavaScript and move all JavaScript code out of the views and into asset files.  Instead of using `<%=question_path(@question)%>` inline, perhaps set the URL you want as the href attribute of the save button.

```
# View
<%= link_to "Save", question_path(@question), :class => "save_button" %>

# JavaScript
...
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  window.location.replace(e.target.href);
}
...
```

Alternatively, you could use data attributes to store the URL instead of the href attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Unfortunately, it's still not working.  And by the way, why is it not a good idea to embed Ruby in the javascript?

Comment: Embedding Ruby code into JavaScript creates a coupling and introduces domain logic into what could otherwise be a static, cacheable file, and it also limits the scope of the solution.  In the portions of your code I used for an example, having the embedded Ruby makes the solution is very specific (always redirecting to a question path), whereas my suggestion is not coupled to a specific URL; it can handle any target with an href attribute of any value.  It may not ever matter for the specific problem you have now, but you never know.

Comment: As far as the problem at hand goes, I'm not sure if I can diagnose anything further with the info that's shown.  The AJAX request + reload was definitely an issue, but obviously not the one that is causing you problems.

Comment: Thanks for your help and for explaining the issues with embedding ruby in the javascript.  Can you or anyone else at least suggest some steps I can take to diagnose the problem?

Comment: I don't have anything specific. Use Firebug or chrome developer tools to set break points in your JavaScript code, and inspect what is being returned from the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it actually turns out that window.location.replace("<%=question_path(@question)%>") was partly the culprit.  I thought I had moved it when I replied earlier but apparently, I hadn't.  That alone wasn't enough, however; I was also missing batchCreate.js.erb, the template file for my action.  That was causing a 500 error and that was what created the error condition on the ajax call.  It seems to be working now.  Thanks very much Wizard of Ogz for your help!